# Python: how resolve TypeError: an integer is required in a loop

Tags: python, list, error-handling, coding-style, list-comprehension

I have a list Dsr

```
>>> Dsr
[59.10346189206572, 40.4211078871491, 37.22898098099725]
type(Dsr)
<type 'list'>
```

I need to calculate the max value and divide each element of the list for this value

```
dmax = numpy.max(Dsr)
RPsr = []
for p in xrange(Dsr):
      RPsr.append(float(Dsr[p]/dmax))
```

I have the following questions:

1) when i run this loop i got thie error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

2) is it possible to convert the loop in a most elegant list comprehension?

Comment: type(Dsr), <type 'list'>

Comment: sorry NPE and thanks. I copied and past wrong. The message of error is "TypeError: an integer is required"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the exception because `xrange()` takes an `int` and not a `list`. You need to use `len()`:

```
for p in xrange(len(Dsr)):
                ^^^
```

Since you're already using NumPy, my advice would be to rewrite the whole thing like so:

```
In [7]: Dsr = numpy.array([59.10346189206572, 40.4211078871491, 37.22898098099725])

In [8]: Dsr / Dsr.max()
Out[8]: array([ 1.        ,  0.68390423,  0.6298951 ])
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you need this:

```
>>> dsr = [59.10346189206572, 40.4211078871491, 37.22898098099725]
>>> the_max = max(dsr)
>>> [i/the_max for i in dsr] 
[1.0, 0.6839042349323938, 0.6298950990211796]
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want to iterate over the actual list. You don't use `xrange` for that:

```
for p in Dsr:
    RPsr.append(float(p/dmax))
```

And you're correct that a list comprehension is the simpler way:

```
RPsr = [p/dmax for p in Dsr]
```